# postgres ltree find next descendant

Tags: postgresql

I have a table where `product_category_path` is ltree

```
product_category_id | product_category_path 
---------------------+-----------------------
                   1 | A1
                   2 | B1
                   3 | C1
                   4 | A1.A11
                   5 | A1.A11.A111
                   6 | A1.A12
```

I want to get only next level **descendant** not all **descendant**.

suppose if i want to get next **descendant** of `A1` then result must be

```
product_category_id | product_category_path 
---------------------+-----------------------
                   4 | A11
                   5 | A11
                   6 | A12
```

Please note my **subquery** will be based on `product_category_id` i.e

```
select * from product_categories where product_category_path <@ (select product_category_path from product_categories where product_category_id=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `SPLIT_PART` here:

```sql
SELECT
    product_category_id,
    SPLIT_PART(product_category_path, '.', 2) AS product_category_path
FROM product_categories
WHERE product_category_path LIKE 'A1.%';
```

Comment: in the like part the path must  be returned from subquery.

Comment: Why? Must be a homework problem. You can just wrap the complete above query is an outer select: `Select * from (select <full query here>) sq;`